# UITableview Indexing with 1 section

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I wonder if you can help me, I've read that it's possible to set up indexed scrolling, even if you have only 1 section in your table view. I have a lot of sorted table entries (over 50) and wish to jump to rows starting A, B, C, D etc as below - I'm pretty new to this and what I have is close, but it's not working properly - can you help ?

My code is as follows :-

```
enter code here 
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[tempArray addObject:@"A"];
[tempArray addObject:@"B"];
[tempArray addObject:@"C"];
[tempArray addObject:@"D"];
[tempArray addObject:@"F"];
[tempArray addObject:@"G"];
[tempArray addObject:@"H"];
[tempArray addObject:@"J"];
[tempArray addObject:@"K"];
[tempArray addObject:@"L"];
[tempArray addObject:@"M"];
[tempArray addObject:@"P"];
[tempArray addObject:@"S"];
[tempArray addObject:@"T"];
[tempArray addObject:@"U"];
[tempArray addObject:@"V"];    
return tempArray;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString     *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {

if(index !=0){ 
    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath
    indexPathForRow:index inSection:0] 
    atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:TRUE];
}
return index;
}
```

Comment: How is it 'not working properly'? Also, look into [(NSArrary*) initWithObjects: ..., nil];

Comment: I'm always amazed when someone thinks that "not working properly" is enough information for us to help them.

Answer (score 5):

Do not return index. Just return 1, which is not a exist section index. Also, need to remove the if judgement.
This makes the section scroll not working, then you can scroll to your own cell manually. I think you need to find the first match with selected alphabet, not just using the index to locate the cell.

To answer the comment below:
It works perfect in my project. Here is my flow, hope it can help you:
Assume you just have one section in that table.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    // Find the correct index of cell should scroll to.
    int foundIndex = 0;
    for (Object *obj in dataArray) {
        if ([[[obj.YOURNAME substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString] compare:title] == NSOrderedSame || [[[obj.YOURNAME substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString] compare: title] == NSOrderedDescending)
            break;
        foundIndex++;
    }
    if(foundIndex >= [dataArray count])
        foundIndex = [dataArray count]-1;

    [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:foundIndex inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You're right sosborn and Adam, I was not explicit enough, apologies, I'm very new to this. What was happening was when I clicked on the index, it would scroll down, but only a line or 2 at a time each time. From an article I thought it would scroll down to the table entries starting with the relevant letter, but I couldn't see how from the code so doubted the info.......yibuyiqu - returning 1 instead of index just scrolls 1 line each time from the top and nothing more.  Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: yibuyiqu : Thanks for your post. It makes sense. I'm having trouble implementing this, Xcode is throwing an error on (Object *obj suggesting I replace with (NSObject *obj. Is this still valid ? Also when substituting obj.YOURNAME should I just use my array name, the same as in for (Object *obj in 'arrrayname') {.  I apologise if these are really basic q's, I'm still very much a newbie ! Thank you very much...

Comment: yibuyiqu : If I can just nail this last problem I'll be home and dry. Does my question make sense ? Thanks.

Comment: Ok I've made some progress and the scrolling is essentially working now,  but have an issue when selecting the last index value as the program now errors. I'll post a separate question on that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: post your answer here how you did it please